# Extracting data from a bundle

Tags: java, android, regex, bundle

AWS SNS is sending a payload to

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final String from, final Bundle data) {
    String message = getMessage(data);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Message: " + message);

    int timeToLive = data.getInt("time_to_live");
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "time_to_live: " + timeToLive);

    String text = data.getString("text");
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Text: " + text);
```

The message is in the form of

```
PushListenerService: Message: {
                           "condition": "normal”,
                           "priority" : "normal",
                           "time_to_live" : 0,
                           "notification" : {
                               "body" : “random gibberish”,
                               "title" : "TEST TITLE”,
                               "icon" : “ic_launcher”
                           },
                           "data" : {
                               “GeoHash” : 1,
                               "text" : "TEST TEXT”
                           }
                       }
D/PushListenerService: time_to_live: 0
D/PushListenerService: Text: null
```

How do I extract the data from this? I would like the PushListener to return Text: TEST TEXT. Can I query a bundle similar to querying a json? Regex?

The getMessage method:

```
public static String getMessage(Bundle data) {
    return data.containsKey("default") ? data.getString("default") : data.getString(
        "message", "");
}
```

Comment: convert message  to json and then retrive data as jsonObject.
let me know if you have doubt

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like this:

```
Bundle payload = data.getBundle("data");
String text = payload.getString("text");
```

Comment: No, data is of type Bundle and doesn't like getJSONObject

Comment: Like this then? :p

Comment: This still returns null on the payload :/

Comment: What is in your getMessage method?

Comment: Edited it in above